# How to execute a shell script inside of emacs?

Tags: shell

I simply want to execute the whole file I am editing right now in a small shell buffer just like I can run my python script.
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What about `Execute script...` and `Execute region` in the `Sh-script` menu?

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that there is a major mode menu! Maybe I should activate the menu-bar that got deactivated in spacemacs sometimes

Comment: Yes, the menus are there to make features more discoverable!  I would not recommend disabling it.

Comment: what is the emacs command associated to this ?

Comment: Use `M-x menu-bar-mode` to toggle it.

Comment: @Tillus Even when the menu bar is disabled, you can access the menu with `f10` (`menu-bar-open`).

Answer (score 5):

You can execute the selected code snippet with `C-M-x` (`sh-execute-region`). (It's the same key binding as `eval-defun` when editing Lisp code, but in sh mode, it executes the region, not the defun around point.) This uses the shell in `sh-shell-file`, which is determined from the shebang line if there is one.

If the script is executable, you can execute it with `C-c C-x` (`executable-interpret`). You'll be given the opportunity to pass arguments. (This command works no matter what language the program is written in, by the way, as long as the file you're editing is executable.)

Neither command maintains a running interpreter in the background, like `run-python` and the associated eval commands do in Python mode. This functionality isn't built in for shell mode. If you want that, you can copy-paste into a `*shell*` buffer.

Comment: Hi. I havn't used Emacs in a while (spent too much time configuring). But if someone can confirm this solution I wil accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a function that will send current line to the shell buffer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286579/emacs-shell-mode-how-to-send-region-to-shell/7053298#7053298

Here is an adapted version that uses `comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output`, so the shell buffer always scrolls to the last output:
https://nistara.net/post/emacs-send-line-or-region-to-shell/

Comment: Hi. I havn't used Emacs in a while (spent too much time configuring). But if someone can confirm this solution I wil accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be to select the entire buffer (`C-x h`) and then use the function to run a shell command on a region as explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871970/emacs-execute-code-in-shell-script-mode.

If I have a split window with the shell script on top and a session in bash below, it would indeed be nice to have a command to send the content of the upper buffer to the bash session and see the output without having to change to the buffer below.

Comment: Hi. I haven't used Emacs in a while (spent too much time configuring and to view time working). But if someone can confirm this solution I will accept it.